# How to I make a StreamReader skip a line when I already have another delimiter?

Tags: c#, delimiter, streamreader

Okey. So I'm making this simple script that spawns blocks from an Array, almost like a tilebased  2d game. But it is not preforming as I want it to, I know why, but I have'nt found any solution. Please help me out if you can :)

So here I run the StreamReader with a space as a delimiter:

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (@"blablabla\path\levelOneMap.txt");
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

    while(s != null)
    {
        char[] delimiter = {' '};
        // Level holder is a string array, wish hold x, s or h.
        levelHolder = s.Split(delimiter, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        s = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

The file he's reading looks something like this:

x x x

x s x

x h x

And so on, so were the x'es are, it will spawn a block. s is a starting block,
and h is just a hole in the ground.

I did a bunch of debug.logs and changed the x, s and h to 1 2 3 4... to see what was going on. Turn out the first 1 2 is fine, but the levelHolder[2] contains both 3 and 4.
How can I make this script understand that it should skip both ' ' and '\n' ?

Comment: As in skip those lines?

Comment: Well... how do I explain this. Running that code, it reads my .txt file and puts my gridsystem into a string array.

let's just say for a minute that my .txt file looked like this:

0 1 2 \n
3 4 5 \n
6 7 8 

I would like the array for contain each value.
But apparently, is does this:

levelHolder[0] = 0
levelHolder[1] = 1
levelHolder[2] = 2 3
levelHolder[3] = 4

And so on...

Comment: Is 2-3 a tab or a space? Try char[] delimiter = {' ','\t'};

Comment: Perhaps just `char[] delimiter = {' ', '\r', '\n'};`  I mean, you even said "it should skip both `' '` and `'\n'`.

Comment: @BenVoigt OP already reads the text file line by line.

Comment: @L.B: Not that I can see.  The only call I see that will return any data is the `ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I missed the that line. Both `ReadLine` and `ReadToEnd` :)

Comment: Yeah, adding more stuff in delimiter fixed my problem! Thanks :D
Didn't even occour to me that it was possible :p

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `ReadToEnd()`, you have the entire file in a single variable, and the stream has reached end-of-file.  Calling `ReadLine()` after that won't do anything.  So you can remove the loop.

Then add whatever delimiters you want, possibly you want all ASCII white-space characters (`{ ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\v' }`).

That's if you want all the blocks placed into a single `levelHolder` array.  If you want each line in its own array, then keep the loop, and change the initial `ReadToEnd()` into another `ReadLine()`.